# Configuring nginx to direct to website in server

Tags: nginx, server, network-programming

I have a remote centOS server running locally on 127.0.0:8000 which I want to proxy with nginx.

I have tested that the server runs on that address and that nginx passes the tests.

When i try to access the ip on my browser I get:[image]

I understand I need to edit the configuration files for nginx. I just don't know how.

I tried going to `/etc/nginx/conf.d/index.conf` (I named my app index because, reasons)

And I write the following:

```
server {
    listen   80;

    server_name  www.<address>.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        root /home/<user>/WebApp/templates;
        index index.html;
    }
}
```

And index.html is on the path I put on root. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, you are trying to hit your nginx IP on port 80 and expect it to redirect to something running on port 8080 on the same server ? Is that what you intend to achieve ? www.<address>.com is something users use to hit your nginx ?

Comment: Edit /etc/nginx/sites-available/default. Keep the proxy_pass and remove the root and index.html. The reason is, since you're reverse proxying, the proxied server is to decide what it will serve, you dont need to specify the root or index page.

Comment: That directory does not exist on centos installations, that's part of the debian package.